# Please either burninate the “correct” tag or merge it into “grammaticality”

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We have 38 questions tagged [correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correct).  This is a horrible meta-tag that does no good.

It should either be removed altogether and put on the blacklist, or possibly merged into the [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) tag.

Comment: I propose an 'incorrect' tag. To be used exactly when 'correct' is used.

Comment: I vote for Trogdor.

Answer (score 6):

I vote for burnination and blacklisting.

Comment: I would too, but I'd include all the tags. They're hopeless.